# How do I make my notification launch an activity when clicked?

Tags: android, notifications

This is the code for my notification, which when clicked, opens `mainactivity` by default, but how do I change it? I want to open `SecondActivity` when it is clicked.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentIntent(
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(),
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .setContentTitle("X ADB").setContentText("client in running")
            .setOngoing(true).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("ticker message")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).build();
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    notificationManager.notify(111, noti);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

And pass pendingIntent in setContentIntent() instead of PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(),
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT